# Compress list of files as their shortest exclusive glob

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

How can I convert a list of files to the minimum-length glob that expands to those files and no others?

E.g. in a directory

```
root
├── one
└── two
```

Then the list `root/one:root/two` can be converted to `root/*`

However if the directory structure were

```
root
├── one
├── two
└── three
```

Then the same list `root/one:root/two` can only be converted to `root/one:root/two` (or `root/*o*` I guess, but I'm not particular about compressing further than an entire extensionless basename).

In

```
root
├── one
│   └── nesting
│       └── nesting
│           ├── left.txt
│           └── right.txt
└── two
```

Then the list `root/one/nesting/nesting/left.txt:root/one/nesting/nesting/right.txt` can be compressed to `root/**/*.txt`.

Is there a way to do this?

Input: `root/one/nesting/nesting/left.txt:root/one/nesting/nesting/right.txt`
Filetree structure:

```
root
├── one
│   └── nesting
│       └── nesting
│           ├── left.txt
│           └── right.txt
└── two
    └── plight.txt
```

Output: `root/one/**/*.txt`

Comment: This feels more like a programming question than a Unix question; just 'cos it's using Unix glob patterns doesn't make it a Unix question.

Comment: @StephenHarris I was kind of hopeful there might be some builtin or tool for it in the unix ecosystem. If there isn't, and we have to manually write a program that does it, then I don't mind this being migrated to SO if that's more appropriate

Comment: Seems to me that for the last one for instance, `*/o*/**/*t` or `**/*g/*t` would be shorter for instance.